# Problems installing Crystal Reports with VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

I am something new with Crystal Reports, but I already went through some tutorials but I have the following problem

Install the following:

[image]

I am working with VS 2017, but when I try to start working with "Reports", it seems that it was not installed

[image]

Am I installing the wrong version?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are installing the runtime (the package you should install on the machines where you deploy your application).

Instead, you should install Crystal Reports package for the Visual Studio IDE.